# Dragging HTML Element in 2 Divs using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

Hi First Look at This Example

jsfiddle.net/bilal2005/HfbaY/

I want to move elements in blue area right now made using two DIV's. All the Elements in Blue divs can be dragged and dropped to all blue area. well elements in Grey will remain in grey area. as they are right now.

Blue area Elements can not be dragged to grey area elements.

Let me know is that possible in any mean or not?

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using HTML5
most of the new browsers do support html5
try the following link

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/